# React setState with function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

I am attempting to setState in a React component using a function callback which is now the recommended way.
It is in the componentDidMount and when I get my jobs data back I need to update the state.
It works when I set it directly but I have attempted may functions callbacks and cannot get it to work.
Sample code provided below with one of my many attempts.

```
async componentDidMount(){
    const jobs = await loadJobs();
    this.setState({jobs});
    //this.setState((prevState, jobs) =>  {return {jobs: [prevState,...jobs]}})
}
```

What is the correct syntax?

Comment: That syntax is fine **if** `loadJobs` returns a promise/is an `async` function, other than that `componentDidMount` is not treated as an async function by React, and so you shouldn't define it as one in your code (the promise it returns will never be consumed, and in particular rejections won't be handled). We'll need more information in order to help you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is a **very** active site. When you post a question (or answer), please *stick around* for a few minutes so you can deal with any questions that come up in comments. People actively want to help you, but can't when you aren't around to clarify things.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to make use of functional setState when you want to update current state based on prevState, in your case it seems like you just want to set the state jobs, you would simply write

```
this.setState({jobs});
```

However if you want to use functional setState, you would still write

```
  this.setState((prevState) =>  {
     return {jobs};
  })
```

You need to update the jobs by getting value from `prevState` and appending the result to the previous state, you would do it like

```
async componentDidMount(){

    const jobs = await loadJobs();
    this.setState((prevState) =>  {
       return {jobs: [...prevState.jobs, ...jobs]}
    })

}
```